# How to fix syntax errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

My website has the following syntax errors and I would love to know what's wrong as I don't have any experience in fixing them.

[image: screenshot of errors]

I will add the code for each error:

1. Error on line 78

   ```
    if(!$this.attr('id')){
     var videoID = 'fitvid' + Math.floor(Math.random()*999999);
     $this.attr('id', videoID);
   }
   $this.wrap('<div class="fluid-width-video-wrapper"></div>').parent('.fluid-width-video-wrapper').css('padding-top', (aspectRatio * 100)+"%");
   $this.removeAttr('height').removeAttr('width');
   });
   });
   };
   // Works with either jQuery or Zepto
   })( window.jQuery || window.Zepto );


   jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery('.upme-video-container').fitVids();   <<line 78
   });
   ```

Comment: `fitVids();` is not a function. Its a very direct error. Chck you JS

Comment: Especially in the second example, you need to show which line is line 355. And show code before the lines as well. Often the errors take place above where it says.

Comment: The first two errors in the screenshot mean that you try to include CSS files in script tags. Also, you're not supposed to include both .css and .min.css files of the same stylesheet.